# Is Cassandra-PDO for PHP stable?

Tags: php, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I'm new to Cassandra and I'm looking for the best way to integrate it with PHP.

As always there are many clients but it looks like most of them are not being supported. From what I've seen the most up to date is PHPCassa, unfortunately it doesn't look like it was designed for CQL (which as I understand is the preferable way to talk to Cassandra).

Cassandra-PDO looks interesting because it's using PDO abstraction, and I can (probably?) use high level libraries like Doctrine or Propel with it. Unfortunately the last commit was pushed about 2 years ago and it was very difficult to compile it (to be fair, it was probably a Mac / Thrift issue). I'm always very paranoiac about building something around "rusty" projects, so my question is:

Is it safe to use Cassandra-PDO with Cassandra 2.x? If it's not a good idea should I forget about CQL and go for PHPCassa or perhaps there is another solution?

Answer (score 1):

This might help: https://github.com/Orange-OpenSource/YACassandraPDO

> "This repository is a fork of:
>   https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-pdo/ We cloned
>   it on GitHub because the original project seemed to be dead.
>
> This version is developped for the CQL3 target only. We do not provide
>   any support for former versions of CQL."

HTH,
Carlo

Comment: Thank you for you reply Carlo. Do you know is this clone used in production for any large system?

Comment: I don't really know. I've been using Cassandra always with Java. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge YACassandraPDO not stable.
Please check this PHP library http://evseevnn.github.io/php-cassandra-binary/

It is written by me, and how to work with it is similar to the PDO wrapper. Maybe it will suit you.

Comment: The link is dead.